# Iterator next method

Tags: java, collections

In `ResultSet` interface there is `next` method which return boolean and then you can directly access the current record by `get` methods

Why `Iterator` from `java.util` just not drop `hasNext()` method and have only `next` method which will move the cursor to next element and return `boolean`?

Comment: I tried something like this while(( o= itr.next() ) != null) , I got NoSuchElementException. If you see implementation of iterator next() method in various classes you will see NoSuchELementException is thrown by checking different condition. For example, Abstractlist has beautiful catch block of IndexOutOfBoundsException to throw NoSuchElementException and in LinkedBlockingDeque class we have next != null check

Answer (score 8):

Because `next()` currently returns the next item.

Java *could* have implemented the iterator pattern in the same way that .NET does, with a `MoveNext()` returning a Boolean value, and then a `Current` property with the "current" value - but it's still two members...

The other alternative is having one return value which encapsulates the two ideas of "is there a value" and "what is the value if there is one" - a sort of `Maybe` type, really. Of course in Java, that means allocating a new object on each iteration, which isn't ideal...

Answer (score 2):

Because you would still need another function to retrieve the value, so nothing would be gained.

In a ResultSet, next() gets you to the next record, or returns false if there is none. Then you do getString()'s, getInt()'s or whatever to retrieve field values. So you write code like:

```
while (rs.next())
{
  name=rs.getString("name"); // or whatever
  ... do something with name ...
}
```

In an Iterator, hasNext() returns a true or false to indicate if there's another record. Then you call next() to retrieve the value. so you write code like:

```
while (iter.hasnext())
{
  name=iter.next(); // or whatever
  ... do something with name ...
}
```

The pattern ends up being pretty similar. It's unfortunate that the implementations are inconsistent. That is, ResultSet.next not only tells you if you're at the end but also advances the positoin, while Iterator.hasNext tells you if you're at the end but doesn't advance the position. But actual use is pretty similar.

It wouldn't really work to try to combine Iterator.hasNext and Iterator.next into one function. How would you know when you reached the end? You could say that it returns null at the end ... but what if null is a valid value in the list? I suppose you could add some magic value, but you'd still have the problem of distinguishing the magic meaning from an entry in the list that just happened to have that value. Like if you have a list of ints, you could say that -1 means end-of-list, but then what if the list includes a value of -1?

The only other alternative I see is to have the next() function return an object that includes both an end-of-list indication and, if applicable, the value. But this would be a pain to use. You'd have to write something like:

```
while (true)
{
  IterableResult ir=iter.next();
  if (ir.end)
  {
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    name=ir.value;
    ... do something with name ... 
  }
}
```

That doesn't seem to gain anything.

Maybe there's another approach that would work better, but I can't think of one. And apparently the creators of the Iterator interface couldn't think of a better way either! :-)

Comment: Well there is difference. ResultSet doesn't do something like first getRecord and then do getXXX on record object. It moves cursor to next object in single statement and you access members of that object by getXXX() methods.  You don't actually get entire record object by getXXX methods.

Comment: @Delta Absolutely true. But the usage would still be similar.

Answer (score 0):

The `next()` method of `ResultSet` is like `hasNext()` of iterator. The majority of other methods of `ResultSet` are instead of single `next()` method of Iterator.

I'd ask other question: why they did not make `ResultSet` implement iterator or at least iterable with generics? I think the answer is that `ResultSet` appears in java before Iterator. Shortly after that a lot of ORM-like tools were introduced, so most people just do not use JDBC directly and do not deal with `ResultSet`.

But I am not historian of JDK, so it is my assumption.

Comment: Also, Iterable.next returns a single value, while after doing a ResultSet.next you may do many getXXX's to retrieve many values. I suppose ResultSet could have been implemented as an Iterator that returns a "Record" object, and you then pull the fields out of the Record. I suppose that would have been more consistent.

Comment: It's true that ResultSet was in Java before Iterator, but Java has had Enumeration since version 1.0, which is the predecessor of Iterator and could have been used if they wanted to do that.

Comment: @Jay, your suggestion about Record is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Iteration of a `ResultSet` can yield an "expected" exception, which doesn't happen with `Iterator`.

Comment: Well, they could have done that. It would have created one more class to deal with, but arguably increased consistency. I'm not sure if there's any big advantage either way. (shrug)